# @jsonproperty serialize different pojo elements in the same attribute name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a simple pojo

```
public class C {
   public String f1;
   public Integer f2;
}
```

At runtime I am sure at most one of the fields is not null (i.e. if `f1` is `"hello"`, I'm sure `f2` is `null`, and vice versa)

I would like to serialize the object using always the same name; for example, with

```
C c1 = new C();
c1.f1 = "hello"
C c2 = new C();
c2.f2 = Integer.valueOf(99)
```

I would like to have `c1` serialized as `{"samekey":"hello"}` and `c2` as `{"samekey":99}`.

I know I can use `@JsonProperty` to set the serialized name, but I cannot set the same name to both the fields.

Is there a way to say that?

Comment: You should be able to use a custom serializer to do this - http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CustomSerializer, checks if f2 value not null then f2 value is copied to f1 and making f2=null.And excluding nulls in the model so always you will get one key&value as other one will be null.

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<C> {

@Override
public void serialize(final C c, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if(c.getF2() != null)  // considering always you need f1 key && value
    {
        c.setF1(c.getF2().toString());
        c.setF2(null);
    }
}
```

}

Annotate serializer & notnull in model as

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class C {
   private String f1;
   private Integer f2;

   //getters & setters
}
```

Hope this is what you are expecting.

Comment: I want to serialize the object, not deserialize it